# Provide option input of one script from another script

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

when login using putty autologin script runs and ask for option to select. Is it possible to provide input to that via another batch file / script? 
example: when i login to say 1.1.1.10 using batch file it will popup window which is asking for input option number from 1 to 10. i want to input that option automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned putty, I am assuming you are working on a windows workstation. And I am not sure if you are familiar with autohotkey but, you can do this pretty easily using a autohotkey code snippet. Something like this:

```
^+P::                                              ; shift-ctrl-P is the hotkey combo to activate this code
send #r                                            ;open windows run dialog box
send \path\to\putty.exe hostname.domain.com{enter} ; stary putty and connect to server
sleep 5000                                         ; wait 5 seconds for connection to establish
send username{enter}                               ; types your username and hits enter
sleep 1000                                         ; wait 1 second for password prompt
send password{enter}                               ; types your password and hits enter
sleep 5000                                         ; wait 5 seconds for your autologin script to run and display menu
send 1{enter}                                      ; type your selection and hit enter (assumes your selection is "1" here
return                                             ; ends code snippet
```

You can change the keystrokes and wait periods according to you particular situation.

autohotkey is a free software (for individual use) and can be obtained from http://www.autohotkey.com